# Needing additional data in managed Version of documents

Tags: marklogic

I need to manage versions of documents. For this I am using MarkLogic's DataManagement (`dls:document-insert-and-manage` and `dls:document-checkout-update-checkin`).

I am trying to include additional data for each version of this documents (e.g. majorversion, minorversion, ...). 
As far as I see, I cannot change the `dls:` Version properties.
Using `dls:document-set-property($uri,&lt;dls:majorversion&gt;1&lt;/dls:majorversion&gt;`) results in

> DLS-SPECIALPROP: (err:FOER0000) Cannot update properties in dls namespace

How can I add information for every version of a documents, so that I can query for them (e.g. give me latest version of a document where majorversion is equal 1)?

Edit:
I tried setting properties using `dls:document-set-property($uri,   $prop)` while updating.

```
dls:document-checkout('/textdoc/4.xml', fn:true(),"checking out 2",3)
;
dls:document-set-property('/textdoc/4.xml', <mainversion>3</mainversion>),
dls:document-update('/textdoc/4.xml', $doc,   "update",   fn:true() )
;
dls:document-checkin('/textdoc/4.xml',   fn:true())
```

Unfortunally I could not get the history of my property. 
Using

```
 let $uri := fn:concat('/textdoc/4.xml')   
 let $results := for $versionuri in dls:document-version-uris($uri)
 return xdmp:document-properties($versionuri)
```

got me none of my properties.

using `xdmp:document-properties($uri)` (on the base uri of the documents) results just in the latest content (`<mainversion>3</mainversion>`)of my properties. All former contents for property mainversion are lost.

I did not found any method retrieving properties in dls. Is there a history of properties?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLS library is not designed to work with major and minor versions, and it won't be easy to retrofit that. Best I can think of right now is to manage major versions as part of the document uri, and have DLS take care of minor versions. You can then use directory queries to limit to a major version of a document.

You could still give document properties a go too, but avoid using the `dls:` prefix. Use a prefix/namespace of your own, or just no prefix/namespace at all.

Something like this might get you close:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" 
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

dls:retention-rule-insert(
  dls:retention-rule(
    "retain-everything",
    "Retain all versions of all documents",
    (),
    (),
    "Locate all of the documents",
    cts:true-query()
  )
)

;

import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" 
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

let $contents :=   
<BOOK>
  <TITLE>Baz Goes to the Disco</TITLE>
  <CHAPTER1>
     <TITLE>Baz Wakes Up to James Brown and Feels Funky</TITLE>
  </CHAPTER1>
</BOOK> 

return (
  dls:document-insert-and-manage(
    "/foo/bar/baz.xml",
    fn:true(),
    $contents
  )
)

;

import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" 
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

dls:document-set-property(
  dls:document-version-uri('/foo/bar/baz.xml', 1), 
  <mainversion>3</mainversion>
)

;

import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" 
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

let $bazbook :=  
<BOOK>
  <TITLE>Baz Goes to the Disco</TITLE>
  <CHAPTER1>
    <TITLE>Baz Wakes Up</TITLE>
    <PARA>
      Baz woke up this afternoon to the sound of James Brown.  Soon
      Baz was feeling a little funky, so he put on his cleanest
      propeller hat and headed out in search of a Disco.
    </PARA>
  </CHAPTER1>
</BOOK> 

return
  dls:document-checkout-update-checkin(
    "/foo/bar/baz.xml",
    $bazbook,
    "Changed the title from Baz Feelin' Funky",
    fn:true()
  )

;

import module namespace dls = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/dls" 
  at "/MarkLogic/dls.xqy";

dls:document-set-property(
  dls:document-version-uri('/foo/bar/baz.xml', 2), 
  <mainversion>4</mainversion>
)
```

HTH!

Comment: I tried with properties ( see my edited Questrion). But if there is no history of properties?

Seems I have to store our versiondata ( majorversion, minorversion, ...) within the content of the document .

Comment: You could use dls:document-set-property together with dls:document-version-uri, but it is a bit cumbersome. I'll update the answer to include some code..

Comment: Thanks ; I'll try it this way. There are some multistatements :-)
As we are using the Java API with ad. hoc queries I will make 2 calls setting properies to the latest-version ('cts:search(fn:doc(), dls:documents-query())' )

Comment: EDIT:  for setting properties this way i get the latest version id with 
`let $lastVersid := fn:max(dls:document-history('/foo/bar/baz.xml')//dls:version-id/text())`
to use with 
`dls:document-set-property(
  dls:document-version-uri('/foo/bar/baz.xml', $lastVersid), 
  <mainversion>4</mainversion>
)`

Comment: Yeah, the multistatements are just a convenience to allow providing a piece of code that could be run as a single query in Query Console..

Answer (score 2):

MarkLogic 9 also supports metadata for documents. You could store additional version info there: https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.documentPutMetadata.

Comment: I don't think DLS works well with hidden metadata. Would be a nice addition though.. ;)

Comment: could be the same as for properties